# how to prove (or disprove) for any $A, B \in \mathbb Z$ there exists factors $X_1, X_2 \in \mathbb Z$ such that satisifies $X_1A + X_2B = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: Definition]

I am trying to prove that every set $(a, b)$ is equivalent with the set of natural numbers. So since this is an ideal in the natural numbers, it is enough to prove that 1 is a member of the set and all other elements will follow.

How i can prove (or disprove) that?

Comment: What if both $a$ and $b$ are even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if $\gcd{(a,b)}=1$ by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).